# Spring mvc test - testing controllers with Autowired annotations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I am trying to create some tests for my controllers using spring test framework.

Following this article: http://blog.springsource.org/2012/11/12/spring-framework-3-2-rc1-spring-mvc-test-framework/ I created this test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:testContext.xml")
public class ServiceRequestControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    private ServiceRequestController productController;

    @Autowired
    private WSServiceRequestIO wsServiceRequestIO;
    @Autowired
    private Open311ResponseMarshaller open311ResponseMarshaller;
    @Autowired
    private Open311GETQueryStringParser open311GETQueryStringParser;
    @Autowired
    private Open311POSTQueryStringParser open311POSTRequestParser;
    @Autowired
    private Open311ResponseFactory responseFactory;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testTest() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/requests"));
    }
}
```

and my testContext.xml is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <bean class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
        <constructor-arg value="utils.webservice.WSServiceRequestIO" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
        <constructor-arg value="open311.model.Open311ResponseMarshaller" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
        <constructor-arg
            value="open311.utils.Open311POSTQueryStringParser" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
        <constructor-arg
            value="open311.utils.Open311GETQueryStringParser" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
        <constructor-arg
            value="open311.model.Open311ResponseFactory" />
    </bean>


    <context:component-scan base-package="open311.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/services*" location="/resources/" />



</beans>
```

now, when I run my tests I get a lot of messages like:

```
2013-04-19 14:33:34 INFO  GenericTypeResolver:216 - Could not determine the target type for type argument [T] for method [public static <T> T org.mockito.Mockito.mock(java.lang.Class<T>)].
```

so there is some problem with inferring types by mockito, but still when I enter the debug mode and inspect my controller I can see that objects were injected correctly. (I am using `@Autowire` annotation in my controller).

Anyway, when I try to run this test I am getting test failure because of

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.getContentType()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1259)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:816)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:740)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:66)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:134)
    at open311.controller.ServiceRequestControllerTest.testTest(ServiceRequestControllerTest.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

what could be the source of my problem? I think that I followed every step from this tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

The `NoSuchMethodError` indicates that you likely have an incompatible version of the Servlet API on your test classpath.

Also, you'll need to include your Spring MVC configuration as well as the bean definition for your `ServiceRequestController` within your test XML config, either directly, via an import, or by declaring a separate XML config file via `@ContextConfiguration`.